# Passing multiple arguments to main in c

Tags: c, arguments, gnu

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])    // Send the path as a parameter
{
    char ptr2[BUFSIZE]; 
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,argv[]);
}
```

Let's say I got this code, if I'm getting multiple arguments in this main (say I do something like "./program car house student phone"), each of them would be a different argument, how do I put them on a va_list?

I don't know how many arguments I'm going to receive, but I need to put it on a va_list, help pls! thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do that, out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm pretty sure standard C doesn't provide any way to do this.

Comment: argc gives the count right? so whats the problem?

Comment: I really can see no reason why anyone would want to do this, or even use variable argument functions in the first place. Smells like pure obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no portable way to do this. However, you can pass an initialized `va_list` down to your other function taking a `va_list` by writing something like

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, argv); // or maybe argc? Whatever, this doesn't make sense anyway
// read: "please don't litter production code with UB"
call_the_function(foo, args);
va_end(args);
```

And, by the way:

> I don't know how many arguments I'm going to receive.

This is not true - that's what the `argc` argument of `main()` is for.

Comment: make that va_start(args, argc) or _maybe_ va_list args = (va_list)args;

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Fair point, but I suspect this is undefined behavior anyway.